# Detectar elemento ya accedido en Array

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy trabajando con Xcode y necesito colocar en distintos imageView una serie de imagenes que tengo en un Array, **con la condicion de que las imagenes que anteriormente ya se han colocado en un imageView, no puedan volver a salir**.

Las imagenes ya se extraen aleatoriamente del Array mediante arc4random_uniform() y se colocan en los elementos, pero se repiten, quiero evitar esto.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías colocar un array de imagenes donde guardes las imagenes que vas mostrando y comparar la imagen extraída con el array anterior, si ya lo tienes guardado no la agregas, caso contrario, sí.

Comment: Puedes crearte otro array con los mismos elementos que el array de las imágenes, de forma que si te sale el elemento 5, el segundo array tenga un valor bool en la posicion 5 con false o true para saber si ya lo has puesto o no.

Comment: Otra posa que puedes hacer es que cada vez que pongas una imagen la elimines del array

Comment: otra variedad del primer comentario mio seria hacerte un struct que tuviera una imagen y un bool que contiene si ya esta puesto o no y hacer un array de ese struct

Answer (score 0):

Para coger las imágenes y asignarlas sin repetir puedes hacer algo así:

```
var images = [UIImage(), UIImage(), UIImage(), UIImage(), UIImage()]

while images.count != 0 { // Ejecuta hasta que el array de imágenes está vacío

    let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count))) // Genera un aleatorio
    imageView.image = images[i] // asigna la imagen al imageView
    images.remove(at: i) // La elimina del array

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me he creado un `struct` llamado `Images`

Donde le pasas un array de `UIImage`

Y que despues puedes llamar a su metodo `getRandomImageNotUsed` para que te devuelva una image del array que no haya sido usada

Una vez que todas las imagenes ya han sido usadas, llamando nuevamente a `getRandomImageNotUsed` te devolvera nil.

## Demo:

```
var image1 = UIImage()
var image2 = UIImage()
var image3 = UIImage()
var image4 = UIImage()

// le asigno nombres para proposito
// de demostrarte el demo.
image1.accessibilityIdentifier = "image1"
image2.accessibilityIdentifier = "image2"
image3.accessibilityIdentifier = "image3"
image4.accessibilityIdentifier = "image4"

var images = Images(images: [image1, image2, image3, image4])

var randomImage1 = images.getRandomImageNotUsed()
var randomImage2 = images.getRandomImageNotUsed()
var randomImage3 = images.getRandomImageNotUsed()
var randomImage4 = images.getRandomImageNotUsed()

print(randomImage1?.accessibilityIdentifier)
print(randomImage2?.accessibilityIdentifier)
print(randomImage3?.accessibilityIdentifier)
print(randomImage4?.accessibilityIdentifier)

var randomImage5 = images.getRandomImageNotUsed()
print(randomImage5)
```

## Output de correr en dos oportunidades el codigo de arriba:

```
Optional("image1")
Optional("image3")
Optional("image4")
Optional("image2")
nil
```

---

```
Optional("image2")
Optional("image3")
Optional("image4")
Optional("image1")
nil
```

## Source Code of Images struct:

```
import UIKit

struct Images {
  private var images: [UIImage]
  private var unusedImageIndexes: [Int]

  init(images: [UIImage]) {
    self.images = images
    self.unusedImageIndexes = Array(0...images.count - 1)
  }

  mutating func getRandomImageNotUsed() -> UIImage? {
    if unusedImageIndexes.count > 0 {
      let randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(unusedImageIndexes.count)))
      let randomIndex = unusedImageIndexes[randomValue]

      unusedImageIndexes.remove(at: randomValue)

      return images[randomIndex]
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva de algo en tu problema, hazme saber si necesitas alguna clarificacion de mi humilde solucion, Saludos compañero!